# Make a ruby file unreadable to a user

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Can I make a ruby file (e.g script.rb) unreadable to a user?

The file is on an Ubuntu (offline) machine. The user will use a local Sinatra app that will use some ruby files. I don't want the user to see the code in some of those files.

How can I do it?

EDIT:
Can I setup the project in a way that the user will be able to start the app but won't have access to specific files in it?

Thanks

Comment: No. You can't, don't even bother trying.

Comment: Are you the machine administrator, and is it feasible to set up the user without admin access to the machine? If so, *thekindofme*'s answer could be made to work by using account management - allow the user to use the HTTP interface, but not see the file system that runs it. This will of course also limit their ability to support the machine in case of problems

Comment: At the moment I think @jigz's answer suits my situation best. Sorry if my question wasn't well put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does that correspond to what you are searching for ?
`chmod yourfile.rb 711`

Comment: I believe so. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment it is literally almost impossible to hide the content of your ruby source file, many people try this in many different ways but it is almost always trivial to reverse engineer. There are some "suggestions" for making your code hidden but they never really work still, here are a few;

1. Obfuscation - The process of making your code executable but unreadable, using a tool like ProGuard for Java (there are ones for most major languages) will try to make your code a mess, and as unreadable as possible while still maintaining execution speed. Normally this consists of renaming variables, using strange characters and generally hiding, moving or wrapping functions in complicated structures.
2. Package the interpreter - You can use a tool like [ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) to package the script up inside an executable with the interpreter and standard library, but anyone with even a tiny bit of experience in reverse engineering will be able to easily tear out the source code given a small amount of time
3. Write a custom interpreter - Now we are getting somewhere with making it harder. Writing a custom interpreter will allow you to compile your script to a "bytecode" that can then be executed. This is of course a very time consuming, expensive and incompatible solution when it comes to working with other code bases.
4. Write most of your code in C and then call out to it via extensions - Again this mostly moves the problem but its still there. It will take more time but anyone can easily pull apart the machine code of the C library you load in and bob is your uncle they have the source code.
5. Many more alternatives - This isn't a comprehensive list, I am probably missing a few ideas or suggestions.

As far as it goes making code unreadable is *hard* a better solution might just to be consider providing a licence agreement with your code. That way, someone reads or modifies the source file you can take them to court for a legal settlement.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your code and its functionality to an external API. And then provide it as a service. This way you don't have to expose your source code to your 'users'.

Comment: Can the external API be on the same machine (the machine needs to be offline)? If so won't the user have access to it?